# [django+mysql]MySQLdb.connect works well, but cannot connect mysql via settings.py

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to connect mysql with django.The follow commands can work well.

```
import MySQLdb
>>> con = MySQLdb.Connect(host = "127.0.0.1", port= 3306, user = "root", passwd = "mycode", db = "test")
>>> con.cursor()
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x020F2230>
>>> cursor = con.cursor()
>>> sql = "SELECT * FROM test.testing"
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
0L
```

when I try to connect database via settings.py, it breaks down, and I can find no clue about it.Here's my config in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'tasty',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'mycode',
        'DATABASE_HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'DATABASE_PORT' : '3306',
    },
}
```

The error message I got from command line, is as follows.I suspect the reason I get error, is django can not fetch proper params for database connection.My environment is win7 32bit, python 2.7.5, django 1.6.7, mysql 5.1, MySQL-python-1.2.4b4.win32-py2.7.Please somebody help me, any suggestion will be appreciate.

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 160,
 in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 132,
 in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127,
 in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 127,
 in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\__init__.py", line 115,
 in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 43
5, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __in
it__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings for the DB should be `HOST` and `PORT`, not `DATABASE_HOST` ... so try this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME' : 'tasty',
        'USER' : 'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'mycode',
        'HOST' : '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT' : '3306',
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks，it works.After restart the cmd window, everything works fine.Can't believe I stuck on such an obvious fault.Thanks again.

Comment: @Simson, yes most of the time we are just missing the obvious :) Btw, please accept my answer if that solves your issues, cheers